# Apache Kafka throw error starting server

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I m trying to up the kafka server but I m having this error. I have no idea what is going on. I m running kafka in a docker container , the version that I m using is 1.0.1 . the zookeeper image is the latest...

```
kafka_1      | waiting for kafka to be ready
kafka_1      | [2018-03-13 12:48:19,886] FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
kafka_1      | org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 0version=1.0.1 for configuration group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms: Not a number of type INT
kafka_1      |  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:713)
kafka_1      |  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:460)
kafka_1      |  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:453)
kafka_1      |  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:62)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:897)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:881)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:878)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
```

I have tried to reduce the version of kafka, I have used the version 1.0.1, 10.0.0 and 0.11.0.2, still receiving the same error

any suggestion how to make kafka works?
thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like the `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms` has a value of `0`, and that's not allowed. I imagine it requires a larger value . Do other versions work? Do you need to specify the config file yourself?

Comment: I v tried with version 1.0.1 and 1.0.0 , is the same, I m going to reduce the version to see

Comment: and with the version 0.11.0.2, is the same

Comment: @HoriaComan with the version 0.10.2.1 works! thanks!

Comment: Your problem was with the group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms  config value.

Comment: @RobertMoskal yes, this config is required in new versions of kafka